# Is it always necessary to get Object from database in @ManyToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I modelled @ManyToMany with a separate joinTable. This code is similar to mine.

```
@Entity
class CourseRegistration {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    Course course;

    LocalDateTime registeredAt;

    int grade;

    // additional properties
    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}

class Student {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    Set<CourseRegistration> registrations;

    // ...
}

class Course {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    Set<CourseRegistration> registrations;

    // ...
}
```

Let's say for a student I want to add new CourseRegistration.
So I would do something like that.

```
Student myStudent = new Student();
CourseRegistration courseRegistrationBiology = new CourseRegistration();
CourseRegistration courseRegistrationMaths = new CourseRegistration();
myStudent.getRegistrations.add(courseRegistrationBiology);
myStudent.getRegistrations.add(courseRegistrationMaths);
```

But this will not work. First I have to set members of Student and Course of CourseRegistration.

So I will go to database to get these objects.

```
Student studentDb = service.getStudent(studentId);
Course courseBiologyDb = service.getCourse(courseBiologyId);
```

Now I can set courseRegistrationBiology .

```
courseRegistrationBiology.setStudent(studentDb);
courseRegistrationBiology.setCourse(courseBiologyDb);
```

Only now I can add it and later update in database.

```
myStudent.getRegistrations.add(courseRegistrationBiology);
```

2 times I had to go to database to get the objects. But actually I only wanted to set 2 ids in my join table. In my opinion this is really bad performance.